# Calculating the velocity of a curve on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, circles, curves

I'm trying to calculate the arc length of the circle using a metric, but I get stuck on how to find the velocity of my curve in the tangent space. So the circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ is defined by $x^2+y^2=1$ for $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and my path is given by $\gamma (t)=(\cos (t), \sin (t))$ (with domain $(0,\pi)$).

Now my first thought was that if I have a chart $\pi_x(x,y)=x$ which maps the upper half of the circle onto the $x$-axis, then the tangent vector should be given by: $\frac{d(\pi_x\circ\gamma)}{dt}(t)=-\sin (t)$. I see that this is obviously false since the curve travels at uniform speed and the chart deleted part of the necessary information.

My second thought was to look at $\gamma$ as a map between manifolds and try to use the definition of the push forward. Now, using the geometric definition of the tangent space, the only thing I get is that for a curve $p$ on $(0,\pi)$ the vector $p'(0)\in T_t (0,\pi)$ is mapped to $(\gamma\circ p)'(0)\in T_{\gamma (t)}\mathbb{S}^1$. I'm however clueless as to what the actual value now in my case.

Could somebody help me out with this?

(Note that I am trying to avoid embedding the tangent space directly in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and using the algebraic definition of the tangent space.)

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand your question, but the tangent vector to $\gamma$ at $(\cos t, \sin t)$ should be $(-\sin t, \cos t)$, shouldn't it?

Comment: It should be if you embed the tangent space with the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but I want to view it as a separate vectorspace in which case it should be just $1\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I try to test if I got the right idea of what you are aiming to: take the inverse of the projection, i.e. $f \colon (-1,1) \rightarrow S^1$ (where $S^1$ now is just the upper half of the circle). Then you can compute its pushforward, taking a vector $v = \alpha'(0)$ at $t = \alpha(0)$, and mapping it into $\frac{d}{dt} f(\alpha(t))_{|t=0} = \frac{d}{dt}\big(\alpha(t),\sqrt{1-\alpha^2(t)}\big)_{|t=0} = \big(v,-\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}v\big)$. This might reply your second thought.

Comment: $\alpha$ should be a curve on $S^1$, so you can't compose $f$ with $\alpha$. To solve this you could just use the projection instead of its inverse, but then you're doing nearly the same thing as in my first aproach, right?

Comment: No, $\alpha \colon (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \rightarrow (-1,1)$, for some $\varepsilon > 0$.